# Android - How to configure proguard

Tags: android, proguard, startapp

I use StartApp to add advertisement, anh use proguard.
When I run apk file (after export application), It forces to close app.

I try to use StartApp, not use proguard, the apk file has no error.

Another way, I try to use proguard, not use StartApp, it also has no error.

Please tell me why ?

this is proguard-android-optimize.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

this is project.properties :

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-20
```

this is code to insert StartApp in Manifest file :

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

this is code in java class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "my developer ID", "my app ID", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StartAppAd.showSlider(this);
        StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use proguard-android.txt file and add the below code

Or if you are using android studio then simpy add below lines to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.startapp.** {*;}
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile,LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-dontwarn android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
```